# How can I interop with existing JS objects?

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop, dart-dev-compiler

I'm trying to write Dart code that will generate a rough equivalent of this:

```
var disposable = vscode['commands'].registerCommand(
    'extension.sayHello',
    function () {
        vscode['window'].showInformationMessage('Hello World!');
    }
);
context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
```

The variables `vscode` and `context` are both globals available in the JavaScript which is executing my Dart (which is being compiled to JS with the Dart Dev Compiler).

I'm happy for context/vscode to be completely untyped for now, but I'm struggling to bend the [JS package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js) to output code like this (eg. if I put @JS() on a stub `vscode`, I get `dart.global.vscode`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the base [dart:js features](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.18.0/dart-js/dart-js-library.html)

Note that `context` happens to be dart's name for the javascript context.

```
var disposable = context['vscode']['commands'].callMethod('registerCommand', [
    'extension.sayHello',
    () {
        context['vscode']['window'].callMethod('showInformationMessage', ['Hello World!']);
    }]);
);
context['context']['subscriptions'].callMethod('push', [disposable]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me put together a quick example on github with `package:js`.

**Edit**: OK, here you go:
https://github.com/matanlurey/js-interop-examples

It took me a couple tries to the package:js syntax correct (we probably need more documentation here and examples), but I ended up creating a "fake" visual studio code API (vscode.js), and interoping with it fine.

Watch out that you need to wrap your functions with `allowInterop` if you expect your examples to work in Dartium.